# Apple Watch support for Stack Exchange app

Tags: discussion, ios-app

I was wondering if the iOS Stack Exchange app was planning to add Apple Watch functionalities, or what's going on in that regard. I haven't seen anything about this, so I thought I'd open a question where some info may come to light.

**Note that I'm not fully expecting anything concrete to be going on, however any ideas, information, etc. could be brought up and discussed here.**

### Possible Functionalities

These functionalities could range anywhere from viewing questions to perhaps writing comments (answers might be too long and difficult to write from the watch, although it's possible for basic answers). Additionally, a handy capability would be to view "Favorite Questions" and your own questions from the watch, as you could view answers and comments on the go and not necessarily need to check your phone or computer. You could then view the comments and answers while deciding if it's necessary that you check the question immediately. Also, you could periodically check questions you've favorited (that need an answer) for an answer. **These features would be more or less helpful depending on which site you're using.**

### Why it might not work

Of course, there are probably some reasons as to why this couldn't work/isn't worth prioritizing. The best I could think of would be the fact that answers could not be written well, formatting would be difficult on the much smaller screen, and maybe the heavy workload of loading all the information onto the watch.

Obviously this isn't too important, as most people don't have the Apple Watch, but I'm rather curious to know if there's a reason why it hasn't happened, there are plans for it in the future, or if it's just not a priority yet.

Feel free to share your opinion and/or correct me if I'm missing something completely obvious.

Comment: Viewing a question.  On a watch.

Comment: I'm happy that I receive the notifications on my Apple Watch. I definitely don't need anything more, I'll just pull my iPhone out if I need to. Its screen is just too small to read anything more than a short text.

Comment: @Glorfindel Fair enough. If you make an answer with this explaining why it shouldn't happen, I'll accept it. I was just looking for justified opinions that make sense (which yours does). Since you have the watch, you would know better than me if it's a good idea anyway

Comment: Should this be tagged feature request instead of discussion?

Comment: @JAL I removed it in the last edit because I didn't intend for this to be a request. I just wanted a discussion regarding this topic (I don't even have the watch), although my wording may be a little off. Doesn't really matter anymore unless something's actually gonna happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple Watch acts as an extension of your iPhone when it comes to push notifications (if you set it up to do so, at least). This works for the Stack Exchange app as well, and I'm happy the way it works: I can read about as much as in the Notification inbox on the website, and decide whether to pull out my iPhone or laptop if I want to *read further* or *react*.

To quote Apple's [design principles](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/human-interface-guidelines/#design-principles) for WatchOS (emphasis mine):

> Designing a great app requires a focused approach. Interactions with Apple Watch are measured in **seconds**, so your app must quickly provide the user with essential information.

Viewing questions and answers takes more time than just seconds. A quick update on your reputation, as @PatrickHofman notices, would work as well, but I feel that developer time is better spent elsewhere. Honestly, there aren't that much Stack Exchange users with Apple Watches around.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much use for an Apple Watch app, besides two common things: notifications and reputation change. The form factor isn't fit for more information than that.

Notifications are already commonly known in the app (with badges and app notifications), reputation is not. If they would implemented reputation changes it would deviate from the current information flow, so I don't expect to see that happen. I personally won't mind just to see notifications.